# What is the right REGEX to extract url from an <li> tag having data-src attribute?

Tags: regex

What is the right regex to extract this url From this li tag which having a data-src attribute this is the URL

```
<li data-src="https://vidshare.tv/embed-k8x9s64oeqyd
.html" data-server="20" style="border-color: #acb953;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the `data-src` value from the `li` tag is done like this:

`<li(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sdata-src\s*=\s*(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\1))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

The value is in capture group 2